# What are the current relationships between Eclipse, Aptana and PyDev?

Tags: django, pydev, aptana

I'm still searching for the ideal development setup for Django, and am having a bit of difficulty sorting out where things currently stand.

I am hoping for something suited for server- as well as client-side development, with support for template-editing and jQuery.

At present I'm using only PyDev in Eclipse and have the following questions:

- Do I scrap the Eclipse installation and start fresh with
  Aptana Studio?  if so,

  -what else would I need before and/or after to achieve the
  environment I described above?
- Is everything going to be supported in the future?
- Am I
  overlooking a better solution that
  doesn't even involve any of these
  tools I've mentioned?

I'm no longer interested in either Java or RoR, if this makes any difference.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Aptana Studio (v3) is the following:

- HTML, CSS, JS editors
- PHP (PDT derivative)
- RadRails
- PyDev
- Eclipse 3.6.2 RCP base

Aptana is not Eclipse rebranded. Aptana Studio is approximately the same as these toolchains:

- Eclipse + Web Tools + PDT + PyDev + ? for rails
- WebStorm + PyCharm + RubyMine + PhpStorm (though, to be fair, RubyMine has more features than RadRails ATM. I don't have an active comparison for PyCharm and PhpStorm)

What to use is dependent on what you need. To get Python editing, JS support and template support, Aptana Studio should be fine. Aptana Studio is built on top of Eclipse, so regular Eclipse plugins work, but you can just as easily put Aptana as a plugin into a straight Eclipse version (i.e. 3.7, if you prefer). That would allow you to jsut uninstall PyDev and add Aptana.

If you don't install Aptana, Django templates won't work, as they need HTML and CSS editor support. You will want an editor that supports jQuery. I'm not sure if Wing IDE or PyCharm include JS support--you might need to purchase WebStorm. Wing IDE looks nice, but it is rather expensive, and you have to pay for the pro version to get many of the most useful features, like integrated source control.

Yes, development and support will continue. Aptana Studio was just purchased by Appcelerator to integrate into Titanium Studio (a mobile development IDE built on top of Aptana Studio).

Answer (score 2):

> What are the current relationships between Eclipse, Aptana and PyDev?

Aptana bought PyDev and integrated it with Eclipse (with different theme) to brand it as "Aptana Studio"

> Do I scrap the Eclipse installation and start fresh with Aptana Studio?

It's the same. I'd rather use Eclipse as the standard.

> Am I overlooking a better solution that doesn't even involve any of these tools I've mentioned?

Personally, I have been developing with django using [Wing IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python/495355#495355) and been happy enough with it, that I don't care enough to look for alternatives. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipde + PyDev plugin is the best solution for now.
Aptana is just a branded Eclipse build, so you won't find too much difference between your Eclipse and Aptana. The only difference is that PyDev is hardly coded inside. I think that this is even bad, because it's impossible to use nightly builds of PyDev in Aptana.

The only alternative for PyDev now is PyCharm. It has a beautiful support of Django but it's not very good for JavaScript programming.

And yes, there is no any plans to stop supporting PyDev as a plugin.